# vsCode+Emmet autocompletion) - insert newline inside div after hit 'tab'

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

by default vsCode does not split div tag into lines:

```
<div></div>
```

As I understand this is because div is a blick element. but I want it to autocomplete like this:

```
<div>
    _
</div>
```

Underline here is cursor position.

Is there a setting for it?

What I've already found is [endWithNewLine](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13942), but it is different setting, for files

Comment: Well if you type <div> and then a return/enter it does exactly what you want.  Indenting the cursor too.  It has nothing to do with whether it is a block element, same behavious on <span>.

Comment: @Mark thank You for response! I type 'div' and hit Tab. Think it would be cool if there was a setting to insert newline/or not

Answer (score 2):

Guys from Github helped:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
    "format.forceIndentationForTags": [
        "div",
        "header",
        "nav",
        "aside"
    ]
},
```