# How to adjust auto-complete behaviour of specific tags in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, tags

Visual Studio Code is pretty smart about how it autocomplete tags. With tags such as  and  when you press enter it automatically does this:

```
<head>
 >
</head>
```

But `<p>` does this:

`<P> > </p>`

Which is great. However `<script>` performs like the latter when it should be like the former. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239095/vscodeemmet-autocompletion-insert-newline-inside-div-after-hit-tab/48175414#48175414 and put `script` in there.

Comment: This seems to work for enmet, which I'm not using.

Comment: Emmet is built-in so you may be using it ;>}  Did you try the suggestion in the link?  It didn't work for you?